# Meteor data context to child template

Tags: meteor

I have a route and a template, that has the right data context as defined in the routes.js:

```
this.route('entrant_view_race', {
    path: '/organise/entrants/:_id/',
    yieldTemplates: navOrganise,
    waitOn: function() {
        return Meteor.subscribe('entrants');
    },
    data: function() {
        return Races.findOne(this.params._id);
    }
});
```

The data context is set to the data function above no problems. Within entrant_view_race template/route we have another template:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        {{> chart_entrant_status}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Now within chart_entrant_status is a subscription which passes a param which is defined in the data context:

```
Meteor.subscribe('entrantStatusCount', this._id);
```

but `this._id` is undefined. I believed that whatever the data context of the parent is passed to child templates unless you explicitly define such as `{{> chart_entrant_status dataContext}}` ? How do I pass the _id of the parent context to the child template (I don't want to use session variables).

EDIT:

`chart_entrant_status` template looks like this:

```
<template name="chart_entrant_status">
    {{#chart_container title="Entrants" subtitle="Status" class="race-status"}}
        {{_id}} 
        <div id="chart"></div>
        {{> table_entrant_status}}
    {{/chart_container}}
</template>
```

Note `{{_id}}` is rendered fine so the context is alive to that point. And the subscription when the template is rendered:

```
Template.chart_entrant_status.rendered = function() {
    Meteor.subscribe('entrantStatusCount', this._id); // this._id is undefined - if I substitute for the actual id as a string Ba48j2tkWdP9CtBXL I succeed....
}
```

But no cigar... struggling to find where I lose the data context...

EDIT2: This returns `this._id` fine...

```
Template.chart_entrant_status.helpers({
    stuff: function() {
        return this._id; // returns the right id in {{stuff}} in the template
    }
})
```

So is the data context not available to `Template.chart_entrant_status.rendered`?

EDIT4: solved. It's this.data._id.... ahhhh

Comment: Where is located your `Meteor.subscribe` exactly ? By default child templates inherit parent data context.

Comment: Thanks, I've added more detail.

Answer (score 1):

`this.data._id` was the correct answer